# The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors, displayes text when I remove the following line "header('Content-type: ' ...."

Tags: php, mysql

as I was trying to load an image from the database on my dev environment, wasn't able to load the image instead giving back error saying "Image cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

```
<?php

require_once 'app_config.php';                 //app config file
require_once 'database_connection.php';        //database connection

try{
//Get the image id.
if(!isset($_REQUEST['image_id'])){
handle_error("No image to load was specified.");
}
$image_id = $_REQUEST['image_id'];

//Build the SELECT statement
$select_query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id = %d", $image_id);

//Run the query
$result = mysql_query($select_query);

//Get the result and handle errors from getting no result
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
  handle_error("We couldn't find the requested image.", "No image found with and    ID of " . $image_id . ".");
 }
 $image = mysql_fetch_array($result);

//Tell the browser what's coming with headers
header('Content-type: ' . $image['mime_type']);
header('Content-length: ' . $image['file_size']);

echo $image['image_data']; 
}catch(Exception $exc){
  handle_error("Something went wrong loading your image.",
             "Error loading image: " . $exc->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Comment: Try using `echo $image;` only instead of `echo $image['image_data'];`  I know it has something to do with `echo`, however if that doesn't work, then it's most likely something in your DB under `mime_type` that's causing it. I've seen a similar case a few weeks ago, but can't remember where on SO it was.

Comment: doesn't work by removing ['image_data'];.

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($image);` after you fetch the result? Truncate the `image_data` key's value to a line or two - I'm expecting it to be quite long...

Comment: @veptemp Your `image_data` or `mime_type` in your DB might be adding something to it, maybe double quotes. View your page source and it will show you any extra characters added that don't belong.

Comment: you may have to create an actual image object with the image data before echoing it.  `$img=imagecreatefromstring($image['image_data']); imagepng($img)`

Comment: @veptemp and if it is adding quotes, then try `echo $image[image_data];` without the single quotes inside.

Comment: array(10) { [0]=> string(2) "12" ["image_id"]=> string(2) "12" [1]=> string(12) "DSC_0986.jpg" ["filename"]=> string(12) "DSC_0986.jpg" [2]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["mime_type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" [3]=> string(6) "250346" ["file_size"]=> string(6) "250346" [4]=> string(250346)

Comment: that is the useful info needed from var_dump I think..@George

Comment: doesn't work either. @Neil

Comment: What does `$image['image_data']` actually contain?

Comment: must be a blob/jpeg image file, the mime_type in my DB is image/jpeg.

Comment: Other things to try are obviously imagejpg instead of imagepng. And if That doesn't work try Base64_decoding the column before imagecreatefromstring.

Answer (score 0):

How are you encoding your image data when you store it? I'd recommend you try to `base64_decode()` it, as that's a common way image data is transmitted/stored.

```
echo base64_decode($image['image_data']);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id = %d", $image_id");


header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);

$im=imagecreatefromstring($row[$i]);
imagejpeg($im).'<br>';


echo("<img src=\"$im.$name\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\" />");
```

this might work..

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error on perfectly legitimate images when the image uses a CMYK colorspace - which many/most browsers do not support. Try loading the original image directly in the browser (without the PHP/DB process) and see if it throws the same error. If it does you should convert the image to RGB using an image editor (or imagemagick if you want to do it server-side).

This is also a known issue with certain FF extensions, namely Skype. Try disabling extensions or another browser to see if this issue affects you.